# Are there security concerns when using DEManager? Is it just a WebCollect for data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

We do not want to use the WebCollect form to add contacts to a list because we want to use data extensions instead. We want to use DEManager to submit form data to to add a contact to a data extension.

All I could find documentation wise is this article in the salesforce documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5

Is there a concern in using this to submit contact data to a data extension? Is this an add/update only endpoint?

Why does the answer to this question: [Using ExactTarget DEManager to update record?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69177/using-exacttarget-demanager-to-update-record) suggest that "is recommended to use the SOAP API data extension functionality for forms that are hosted outside of the Salesforce Marketing Cloud"?

Comment: The concern is that you would be sharing your clientid and data extension key publicly (assuming the html form is on a public website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David mentions - The concern is that you would be sharing your clientid and data extension key publicly (assuming the html form is on a public website).

DEManager has its limitations, so using SOAP or REST API (or the SDK) will open up more possibilities for you as is then a Server Side call so it more secure than DEManager.

DEManager by itself works fine, is safe - provided you understand ClientId and DE External Key are visible in source. My malicious mind just thinks you could use clientId to contact support and attempt a social engineer hack I.e. attempt to identify themselves as the client using the clientid.

I haven't heard of any hacks or data breaches using DEManager, but I personally don't use it as I prefer building the integrations using pure API code as DEManager would otherwise limit me when attempting some sosphiciated functions.

Comment: Would it also not be a possibility that someone could copy the code, place it on another site and then be able to write rows to the data extension without the client's knowledge?