# DEmanager - Success page issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I'm making an Cloud Page by code, when the user fills in all the fields and presses the send button he is not redirected to the correct page, but to a "default" page:

[image]

[image]

What i can do?

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8rc0SAB

Did you update Domain Allowlist? Also, I STRONGLY recommend re-posting with values blacked out. Also (also), b/c someone is going to mention it, DE Manager in not recommended approach, having the client id exposed opens up security risks - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213795/are-there-security-concerns-when-using-demanager-is-it-just-a-webcollect-for-da

Comment: I would also recommend using cloudpage/smartcapture/ampscript and not DE manager