# Can we use Web collect to update a Data Extension from a website?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, email-studio

I want to update Data Extensions from client website. Just wanted to check is it possible to update DE using Email Studio Web Collect? 
From the Documentation, list are there that can be updated.
Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Data Extensions you need to use DEManager

[Using ExactTarget DEManager to update record?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69177/using-exacttarget-demanager-to-update-record)

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5

For a shared Data Extension try this, use DEManager to add your rows to a regular data extension, then run a sql query to grab all of those rows and put them in a shared data extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! i have done that but i can only update BU specific DEs. How to update Shared Data Extensions with this method?

Comment: Updated, see above